# Create Animal object with substrings

Tags: java

I am focusing on the method `readDataFromFile()` and it can read text separated data such as:

```
Bird    Golden Eagle    Eddie
Mammal  Tiger   Tommy
Mammal  Lion    Leo
Bird    Parrot  Polly
Reptile Cobra   Colin
```

Currently I have separated each word such as: `Reptile, Cobra. Colin` using the scanner method.

- The only thing I need to do is create and add an Animal object to the zoo with these substrings.

An `Animal` consists of: a `name` and a `species`.

Any help or advice to guide me on how I could achieve this would be amazing.

***MyZoo Class:***

```
public class MyZoo
{
   private String zooId;
   private int nextAnimalIdNumber;
   private TreeMap<String, Animal> animals;
   private Animal animal;

   public MyZoo(String zooId)
   {
      this.zooId = zooId.trim().substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
      nextAnimalIdNumber = 0;
      animals = new TreeMap<String, Animal>();
   }

   public String allocateId()
   {
      nextAnimalIdNumber++;
      String s = Integer.toString(nextAnimalIdNumber);
      while ( s.length()<6 )
         s = "0" + s;
      return zooId + "_" +  s;
   }

   public void addAnimal(Animal animal)
   {
      animals.put(animal.getName(), animal);
      this.animal = animal;
   }

   public void readDataFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      int noOfAnimalsRead = 0;

      String fileName = null;

      JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
      FileDialog fileDialogBox = new FileDialog(mainWindow, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
      fileDialogBox.setDirectory("."); 
      fileDialogBox.setVisible(true);

      fileName = fileDialogBox.getFile();
      String directoryPath = fileDialogBox.getDirectory();

      File dataFile = new File (fileName);
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);
      //System.out.println("The selected file is " + fileName);

      scanner.next();
      while(scanner.hasNextLine())
       {
       String type = scanner.next();
       String species = scanner.next();
       String name = scanner.next();
       System.out.println(species + ": " + name);
       scanner.nextLine();
       }
       scanner.close();
    }

}
```

***Animal Class:***

```
public class Animal
{
   private String id;
   private String species;
   private String name;
   public Animal(String species, String name, MyZoo owner)
   {
      id = owner.allocateId();
      this.species = species;
      this.name  = name;
   }

   public String getId()
   {
      return id;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   public String getSpecies()
   {
      return species;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return id + "  " + name + ": a " + species;
   }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you already have most of the code done here..? What exactly are you struggling with. You're already extracting the species and name with your Scanner(), just create a list of Animal objects and send the ids to your zoo

Comment: What is your question? It's all there?!

Comment: I suppose my question is, how would i add these substrings into the Zoo treemap without creating an animal object??

Comment: You could change `TreeMap<String, Animal>` to `TreeMap <String, String>`. The key can be the Animal name and the value can be the Animal species. This removes the need for the `Animal` class.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have found the name and the species, you use the constructor of `Animal` to create the instance, then add it to your zoo :

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String type = scanner.next();
    String species = scanner.next();
    String name = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(species + ": " + name);
    scanner.nextLine();

    Animal a = new Animal(species, name, this); // 'this' bevcause its requires a MyZoo 
    this.addAnimal(a);
    // can inline : addAnimal(new Animal(species, name, this));
}
```

Comment: would it be possible to add the substrings to the zoo WITHOUT creating an animal object?

Comment: @MelissaStewart your zoo is an Animal container, so how add them without create an Animal ? And if you don't create animal, the TreeMap and the Animal class becomes useless and it result on a poor model

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why creating an animal object is against my professor, just asked him and he stated that he didn't want me to. Would there be any reason why NOT creating an animal object might be better?

Comment: @MelissaStewart There is no reason at all, to not create an animal to have a complte and logical model. It would mean that class Animal can go to bin, and also your TreeMap ^^

Comment: Would you have any idea how I would remove a substring? for an example the first line of the text file is: 'Bird Golden Eagle Eddie' which is 4 substrings however how would i remove the 'Bird' so that 'Golden becomes the first substring read?

Comment: @MelissaStewart yes i have. But I’m not here to solve all your homework, you’d better learn more Java to achieve what you need